# Can resources be used to save important values?

Tags: c#, .net, resources

Can resources be used to save important values such as the string connection of database? the question is: it is safe? or a not authorized people can see the values?
Thanks!

Comment: I think you're asking if it's secure to store a database connection string in a resource file like "app.config"?  Q: Could you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String resources embedded in an executable file are not secure. They can be seen by anyone with common resource-inspection or disassembly tools. Obscure, perhaps, but not secure. Do not store passwords in string resources.

Comment: @The Mask: I *asked* you to clarify your vague question.  Competent_tech improved it a bit.  If you're indeed talking about .Net configuration files, then yes: you CAN encrypt string data as needed:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx

Comment: The question asked about resources (resx), not config files.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't store any security-critical plain text values in the resources.

If you must store values, such as the database connection strings, you should encrypt them first.

Answer (score 0):

Securing Connection Strings:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Encrypting Configuration Sections:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx

PS:

These methods are MORE secure than hard-coding a connection string in your .exe!